# pagination in entity framerowk

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What is the best practice for pagination in Entity framework?
Should one hit database twice, one to get total record count and second to get the records?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a LINQ query which uses the Skip and Take operators.

Example - Page 1:

```
someObject.Skip(0).Take(10)
```

Example - Page 2:

```
someObject.Skip(10).Take(10)
```

Then you can define a page size variable and use that as the parameter to the `Take` and `Skip (page size variable * (page number - 1))` operator.

And yes, one hit to get the total record count, to get the total number of pages.

Comment: Not for nothing, but when you are working with a custom Linq query, ex: where 'some data' = 'some data' and so on. I would have to write this query twice and modify the first for simple counting proposes!? It just doesn't seem like the right way to code! Just saying

Comment: @JasonFoglia You need to know the total matching record count if you want to allow them to navigate to the next/previous/first/last page and display something like "Page 3 of 10". Obviously you would only need to fetch the total number of records the 1st time, not when the user is navigating between the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination will probably come with dynamic filtering and sorting as well.
A clean way to handle the situation is to encapsulate all the result set and the related metadata (page size, current page number, etc.) in one class.
[EntityFrameworkPaginate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkPaginate/1.0.0) is a nuget package which provides an elegant solution to pagination. So, the way it works is you set up your dynamic filtering and sorting and you will get a **Page** object as result which will have the result along with the metadata. (CurrentPage, PageCount, PageSize, RecordCount and Results).

If you have dynamic filters based on separate conditions, then you can create a Filters object. Add the filter expression and the condition the the filter object.

```
 var filters = new Filters<Employee>(); 
 filters.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText), x => x.LoginID.Contains(searchText));
 filters.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobTitle), x => x.JobTitle.Equals(jobTitle));
```

Similarly set up your dynamic sorting in the **Sorts** object.

```
 var sorts = new Sorts<Employee>();
 sorts.Add(sortBy == 1, x => x.BusinessEntityID);
 sorts.Add(sortBy == 2, x => x.LoginID, true);
```

Now, call the Paginate extension method on your db set to get the paginated results.

```
 context.Employees.Paginate(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);
```

This approach reduces the code you have to write without having any implications on the performance. A detailed example is [here](http://harshw.com/implementing-dynamic-filtering-sorting-pagination-entity-framework/) in the link.